# persistent Syntax Error in if statement inside for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to debug this Python game.

When I run it, the error just says:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax, with a carrot under the '0' on the line that says:

```
if alien.eggs == 0
```

Here is the full statement:

```
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(alien,powerups,True)
for hit in hits:
    if hit.type=='magic':
        alien.magic+= random.randrange(10,30)
        if alien.magic:
            if alien.eggs == 0    #error on this line under the 0
                game_over = True
```

I've tried playing with spaces and indenting, but nothing fixes it.

Comment: You're missing a colon after `== 0`

Comment: Compare the error line with this line: `if hit.type=='magic':`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a colon after the zero